# Looking for app to fill credit card info on form after swipe from a card reader

Tags: iphone, ipad, applications

I'd like to swipe a credit card on my iPad and have it autopopulate form fields on a web page. Does anyone know of an an app and card reader that do this? I found a few for desktops like [SmartSwipe](http://www.smartswipe.ca), but I'm having trouble finding something similar for iPad.

Answer (score 1):

They clearly exist, but not necessarily free; I googled a bit and found

http://idtechproducts.com/component/content/article/438-mobile-readers/125-imag-pro-mobile-magstripe-reader.html

Assuming you already have a card reader, have you tried contacting its manufacturer to see if they have any recommendations?  Most iOS app/reader combos will be full POS or transactional systems, like Square.

Comment: There are plenty of card readers and apps, but they all seem to deposit directly into an account or require you to use the form in the app. I want to simulate typing on the keyboard on a form on a specific web page.